# how to fill an empty month based on the sum of months?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table that only contains date data, and I want to count the number of times that data is in the same month, and for that problem it's finished, and now I get a new problem that is the missing month, this is because there is no data on the month that. And now I want to add the empty month with default value 0 even though the month is not in the table. Can anyone help me based on my query?

this my data

```
start_date  |end_date
------------------------
 2018-10-01 |2018-10-02
 2018-01-04 |2018-02-04
 2018-08-01 |2018-10-01
```

this my query

```
select month(month_table) as month_table, sum(cstart) as cstart , sum(cend) as cend from ((select `start_date` as month_table, 1 as cstart, 0 as cend from newdata) union all (select `end_date`, 0, 1 from newdata ) ) dd group by monthname(month_table), month(month_table) order by month(month_table)
```

and the results is

```
  month_table|cstart|cend
      1      |  1   |  0
      2      |  0   |  1
      8      |  1   |  0
      10     |  1   |  2
```

and i want to add new query so my results will be

```
  month_table|cstart|cend
      1      |  1   |  0
      2      |  0   |  1
      3      |  0   |  0
      4      |  0   |  0
      5      |  0   |  0
      6      |  0   |  0
      7      |  0   |  0
      8      |  1   |  0
      9      |  0   |  0
      10     |  1   |  2
      11     |  0   |  0
      12     |  0   |  0
```

this my fiddle
  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c18b5f/3/0

if anyone can help me please help me, im so confuse follow this method
[Duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358457/mysql-filling-rows-for-missing-months?noredirect=1&lq=1%22Duplicate%22)

Comment: create a help table that contains 1 - 12. Outer join.

Comment: Or to add to @jarlh 's comment a delivered table (subquery) which contains 1- 12  and `LEFT JOIN`.. Besides this question is been asked before search on stackoverflow with "calendar tables"

Comment: @RaymondNijland i'm getting error when trying that, on him case using number, and my case using datetime

Comment: @RaymondNijland this is my error  "execute command denied to user 'user_9_b6ce9c'@'%' for routine 't1.month'" im testing using sql fiddle