# use month names instead of numbers, in union select mysql

Tags: mysql

First, I just used union, and I don't really understand it.
basically, to change the name of the month I usually use

```
select MONTHNAME (date)
```

But in this case I dont know Union more deeply so it is very confusing to change the number of months to the name of the month. Can you help me? please don't just give an answer but please also include an explanation.

this my query, and fyi this query was helped by the 'sticky bit' in my previous topic.

```
SELECT m.month month_table,
       coalesce(s.count, 0) cstart,
       coalesce(e.count, 0) cend
       FROM (SELECT 1 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 2 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 3 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 4 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 5 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 6 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 7 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 8 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 9 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 10 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 11 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 12 month) m
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT month(n.start_date) month,
                              count(*) count
                              FROM newdata n
                              GROUP BY month(n.start_date)) s
                      ON s.month = m.month
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT month(n.end_date) month,
                              count(*) count
                              FROM newdata n
                              GROUP BY month(n.end_date)) e
                      ON e.month = m.month
       ORDER BY m.month;
```

I have tried to replace all 'month' to 'monthname' but the results is 0.

Before i change month to monthname

```
 month_table|cstart|cend
      1      |  1   |  0
      2      |  0   |  1
      3      |  0   |  0
      4      |  0   |  0
      5      |  0   |  0
      6      |  0   |  0
      7      |  0   |  0
      8      |  1   |  0
      9      |  0   |  0
      10     |  1   |  2
      11     |  0   |  0
      12     |  0   |  0
```

and when i change month to monthname the results be

```
month_table|cstart|cend
      1      |  0   |  0
      2      |  0   |  0
      3      |  0   |  0
      4      |  0   |  0
      5      |  0   |  0
      6      |  0   |  0
      7      |  0   |  0
      8      |  0   |  0
      9      |  0   |  0
      10     |  0   |  0
      11     |  0   |  0
      12     |  0   |  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `CONCAT` to convert your month number into a date string that you can then pass to `MONTHNAME` i.e. change the first line of your query to:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(CONCAT('2018-', m.month, '-01')) month_table,
```

Output (for your sample data from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51880711/how-to-fill-an-empty-month-based-on-the-sum-of-months)):

```
month_table     cstart  cend
January         1       0
February        0       1
March           0       0
April           0       0
May             0       0
June            0       0
July            0       0
August          1       0
September       0       0
October         1       2
November        0       0
December        0       0
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5c998/4)

Answer (score 0):

Most people just create look up table for this kind of thing, populate it once then use it. Not only does it perform vastly better, but it’s easily understood and reused.

Another common tick is to create a “calendar” table that contains all the dates within a decade or so, with day names, public holiday indicators, etc, which makes writing queries that output data for each day, even if there is no data for that day, super easy. And it’s completely portable.

Forget the SQL Kung Fu and apply KISS.

Comment: A decade? All dates for the next millennium is a depressingly tiny table.

Comment: @Strawberry you are 100% correct. But if you want completeness of public holidays etc, you only need to cater for as many days in the future as you will be working there :)

Comment: it's very difficult for me to understand it. I think i need more basic lessons before do it.